# How to select an autogenerated Record and additional Data with a join in jooq?

Tags: java, jooq

Assume you have two tables, `foo` and `bar` and a table that matches `foo`s to allowed `bar`s:

```
foo             bar
+----+-------+  +----+-------+
| id |fooName|  | id |barName|
+------------+  +----+-------+
| 1  | aa    |  | 10 |  xx   |
| 2  | bb    |  | 11 |  yy   |
| 3  | cc    |  | 12 |  zz   |
+------------+  +----+-------+
```

n:m Relation between `foo` and `bar`

```
foo_x_bar
+--------+--------+
| foo_id | bar_id |
+-----------------+
| 1      |  10    |
| 1      |  11    |
| 2      |  11    |
| 3      |  12    |
+-----------------+
```

Now, given any `foo.id` (say `1`) I want a list of *all* `bar`s and whether they are applicable for `foo.id` `1`. I can do this with this SQL:

```
SELECT bar.id, bar.barName, foo_x_bar.foo_id 
FROM bar LEFT OUTER JOIN foo_x_bar
ON bar.id = foo_x_bar.bar_id AND foo_x_bar.foo_id = 1;
```

That gives me the following result:

```
+--------+-------------+------------------+
| bar.id | bar.barName | foo_x_bar.foo_id |
+--------+-------------+------------------+
|   10   |   xx        |       1          |
|   11   |   yy        |       1          |
|   12   |   zz        |      null        |
+--------+-------------+------------------+
```

I.e.: I get a complete list of `bar`s and know wether they are referenced by the `foo` with `id` `1`. (All rows with a `null` for `foo_id` are not referenced)

So now (finally) to my question: how to achieve this with jooq, so I get the nice `BarRecord` classes jooq autogenerates for me. This is how far I got:

```
List<Record3<Long, String, Long>> result = 
create.select(BAR.ID, BAR.BARNAME, FOO_X_BAR.FOO_ID)
.from(BAR).leftOuterJoin(FOO_X_BAR)
.on(BAR.ID.eq(FOO_X_BAR.BAR_ID))
.and(FOO_X_BAR.FOO_ID.eq(fooId))
.fetch();
```

This is all good, but if `Bar` happens to have a lot more columns, this gets tedious and I would like to use the `BarRecord` class jooq autogenerates for me.

How can I get a `Record2<BarRecord, Long>` instead?

=============== Edit ==============

Based on the correct answer below, this is the complete code we came up with:

```
public static class BarMapper 
implements RecordMapper<Record, Pair<BarRecord, Boolean>> {
    //the boolean indicates if a matching FOO is present
    return new Pair<BarRecord, Boolean>(
        record.into(BAR), 
        record.getValue(FOO_X_BAR.FOO_ID) != null);
}

public List<Pair<BarRecord, Boolean>> selectBarsForFooId(final long fooId) {
    create.select(BAR.fields()).select(FOO_X_BAR.FOO_ID)
    .from(BAR).leftOuterJoin(FOO_X_BAR)
    .on(BAR.ID.eq(FOO_X_BAR.BAR_ID))
    .and(FOO_X_BAR.FOO_ID.eq(fooId))
    .fetch(new BarMapper());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
create.select(BAR.fields())
      .select(FOO_X_BAR.FOO_ID)
```

`BAR.fields()` is more or less the same as `BAR.*` in SQL.

You currently (as of jOOQ 3.4) cannot generate nested records in your result via the jOOQ API. This is a pending feature request:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2360

In order to map (partial) records into a well-typed `BarRecord`, you can simply call [`Record.into(Table)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#into-org.jooq.Table-)

```
BarRecord bar = Record.into(BAR);
```

Comment: That already helps a lot, thank you. Is there a way to call the Mapper for `BarRecord`? I did not find it anywhere, but it must be autogenerated to fill the `BarRecord` in `selectFrom` queries, right? If I had that mapper, writting a custom mapper for a `Record2<BarRecord, Long>` would be much less boilerplate.